# How can I put repeated jQuery code into a subroutine or function?

Tags: jquery

I am a jQuery newbie and I have created my first functioning program with it. It contains a series of hyperlinks on an image, and when you click on a word (the hyperlink), it invokes some jQuery that changes the look of the page, and calls an Ajax routine that performs a search and displays its results.

My problem is that I have a number of different hyperlinks, all of which do essentially the same thing, with only a simple character string that is different in the jQuery that processes it.

I am sure there is a good way to create a chunk of code once that can be executed passing the character string as a parameter, but I cannot yet figure out how to do this. Can someone suggest the cleanest way to do this?

Some of my code follows, but PLEASE IGNORE THE ## NOTATION as this is in ColdFusion which converts it to a single # before it hits the browser.

```
$( "##Shoulders" ).click(function() {
    $("##div1").animate({ height:0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty();
    $("##div2").animate({ height:0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty(); 
    $('##div3spacer').ScrollTo();
    $("##div3").load("ThreeSearchExercise.cfm?A=Shoulders", function () {
        $('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT(); 
        });
    }); 

$( "##Arms" ).click(function() {
    $("##div1").animate({ height:0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty();
    $("##div2").animate({ height:0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty(); 
    $('##div3spacer').ScrollTo();
    $("##div3").load("ThreeSearchExercise.cfm?A=Arms", function () {
        $('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT(); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: strongly suggest you put the JS in a separate file so you don't have to do the coldfusion `##` escaping which can be confusing.

Comment: I think that the only people it confuses are those who don't program in ColdFusion. By separating the JavaScript into its own file it makes it a little harder to maintain and increases the chance that the main web page can get out of synch with the JavaScript.

Comment: vast majority of all javascript is delivered to pages from external files

Comment: also whenever you have to mix in server language specific syntax into javascript it makes that javascript far less portable for other uses

Comment: Yeah I know all the arguments (I've been programming for 50 years, really!) but when I write a web page I'm mixing HTML, CFML, JavaScript, jQuery and SQL and the more separate modules I create for a page, the tougher it becomes to keep them all straight. Hey, I'm all for separating things that are used in more than one place, but when it is just a language switch inside one logical chunk of programming, I see no upside to putting different language elements in different files.

Comment: understandable...am in the middle of porting a site into wordpress from 15 year old coldfusion that wasn't well structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that changes is `A` parameter. So you can do this

```
function clickHandler() {
    $("##div1,##div2").animate({ height: 0 }, 500).css('overflow','visible').empty();
    $('##div3spacer').ScrollTo();
    $("##div3").load("ThreeSearchExercise.cfm?A=" + this.id, function() {
       $('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT();
    });
}
```

And bind like this

```
$('##Shoulders, #Arms').click(clickHandler);
```

Comment: as a side note, you could use this too: `$("##div1, ##div2").animate({ height: 0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty();`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining anonymous functions inside each click() call. Use a single named function instead.

```
function handleClick() {
    function() {
        $("##div1").animate({ height:0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty();
        $("##div2").animate({ height:0 }, 500).css('overflow', 'visible').empty(); 
        $('##div3spacer').ScrollTo();
        $("##div3").load("ThreeSearchExercise.cfm?A=Arms", function () {
            $('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT(); 
        });
    }
}

$( "##Shoulders" ).click(handleClick); 
$( "##Arms" ).click(handleClick);
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference between this response and the one above when you say "You are defining anonymous functions inside each click() call".

Comment: It's the same solution. I just wasn't fast enough. :)
In JS there are several ways to define functions, and they have different nunaces.  See http://www.unicodegirl.com/function-statement-versus-function-expression.html